# Displaying the date in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

If I run the following code:

```
[textView setString:  [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello %@. Today is %@", [ textField stringValue ], [ NSDate date]] ];
```

it says

> Hello Phenom. Today is 2010-07-06
>   02:37:43 -0700

How can I fix it so that it instead says

> Hello Phenom. Today is Tuesday, July
>   6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
You can see an example in the doc...